# PHP code breaking on calling require function

Tags: php, require

I have a code snippet as follows

```
echo "calling require";
require ('../includes/functions/database.php');
echo 'require called';
```

my code echoes the first command and prints "Calling required."

as soon as it hits require function my code breaks and does not execute any further, as a result I don't get to print the last echo "require called"

What could be the possible reason?

Comment: by the way I have confirmed the existence of file at the location I have specified in require parameter.

Comment: Any `exit()` in your database.php file ? Can you show us this file ?

Comment: 'If you use the require directive to load a file, your script will die if the file is not found or the user that is running the web server does not have read access to it.' --php.net   Check your permissions

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` above the line that causes the script to halt and post the output.

Comment: Check that the current working directory (use getcwd()) is where you think it is... it isn't always the location where the file was loaded.

Comment: first of all a big thank you to all of you guys.. a beginner like me would have spent days digging the code. I am absolutely stunned by the rapid response. Special thanks to salman A, using his code i was able to find out what was the error actually. Actually the page has another require call at the top which has a function, and i dont know why on earth the previous coder has declared two copies of the same function which caused it to crash giving the error "Cannot redeclare....". Thank you again.

Answer (score 4):

Let php show error messages and you will find the error pretty quick.

Add these lines before the require

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: thanks remy, i was able to see and then fix the error by using error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); above the rogue line. thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

The required file:

- doesn't exist
- exists, but your relative path doesn't match it's location
- is not readable
- has syntax errors itself

Any of those can be the reason.

Comment: Btw, downvoting other people's answers doesn't make yours better.

Comment: thanks narf, i was able to see and then fix the error by using error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); above the rogue line. thanks for your input. i agree with your stance buddy on downvoting..:)

Answer (score 0):

Requiring a file in PHP by using relative path must be prohibited. The relative path depends on the PHP file being called first by the browser. ALways require or include files using absolute path.

Comment: thanks jerome, i was able to see and then fix the error by using error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); above the rogue line. thanks for your input.

Answer (score -1):

The file may exist but may be unreadable. Use `is_readable()` to check it:

```
if(is_readable('../includes/functions/database.php')) {
   echo('ok!');
}
```

Also, there may be an error or `die()` inside database.php file which prevents further execution. Check database.php for errors and `die` / `exit` calls.

---

Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` at the beginning of your scipt to debug errors as Salman A suggested in the comments.

Comment: thanks kdzwinel, i was able to see and then fix the error by using error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); above the rogue line. thanks for your input.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want your code to be executed no matter if the `require` did work, you could use `include` instead of `require` as it generates a warning instead of a fatal error.

Comment: thanks fero, i was able to see and then fix the error by using error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); above the rogue line. thanks for your input.